# SSRS: How do you hide the label for one data field in a Line Graph axis while leaving another visible?

Tags: reporting-services, linegraph, sql-server-data-tools

[image]I have two category groups defining my x-axis. One for the version number and one for the date that a test ran. Currently it displays both and is ordered by the date. I don't want the current ordering to change, but I DO want to hide the dates and just display the version numbers on the x-axis.  How do I go about doing that? I'm not finding much help regarding the "HideAxis" custom expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going about this the wrong way.  The simple solution was to do the following:

- select the drop down menu from the version datapoint under the category groups section of the Chart Data interface.
- From there you can select sorting, and then select any data point you want from the Sort By drop down.

[image: Like so...]